# Intercept WiFi requests

Tags: java, wifi, traffic

I have a webapp running on a PI which I use to turn my PC on and off. I'd like to also be able to turn on the AV Amplifier so I can switch it on while I'm away to deter would-be burgulars.

The AV controller is a Yamaha 675 and has an android app I use when at home. How can I best intercept that traffic so I can figure out how to send the commands from my own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, have discovered a free android app called tPacketCapture which monitors requests made my the phone and produces a pcap file I can read in Wireshark. Also then discovered that my amp simply serves a webpage with plaintext JavaScript so I can figure out the requests from there. Bingo!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a option to sniff your traffic as long it doesnt go over HTTPS.

You can actually let your phone connect to an proxy on a local network and intercept the traffic there. You could use Burp for this. They have a free version
https://portswigger.net/burp/

- Setup Burp on your pc and let it listen on 0.0.0.0.
- Configure your phone to the proxy of your pc on your network.
- Use Burp to intercept and inspect your traffic.